# Android Crash Occurs when Changing from PIN to tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, crash

I'm trying to work out some basic kinks and there's something I can't figure out. Upon runtime the app displays a prompt for a PIN number along with a button to confirm. Once you enter the correct PIN number (tentatively just "0000") you proceed to the next activity.

```
public class RewardTimerMainActivity extends Activity {
//Default screen, this comes up when the app is launch, prompts for pin or recovery e-mail
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListInstalledApps.listForActivity(this);
    System.out.println("Starting reward timer main, new code!");
    setContentView(R.layout.unlock);
}

public void submitPIN(View view) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pinText);
    if (editText.getText().toString().equals("0000")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

Now the second activity consists of multiple tabs. I know the layout is functional, and in fact the associated code is correct because I tried running it independently and it works fine.

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
    spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1");

    TabHost.TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
    spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2");
    spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec3=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 3");
    spec3.setIndicator("Tab 3");
    spec3.setContent(R.id.tab3);

    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
    tabHost.addTab(spec3);


}
```

}

The problem is that while both pieces of code seem to work independently, when I run them in tandem, and I enter the correct PIN and try to proceed to the second activity, it crashes. Can someone explain why?

Comment: post your error log. I think you should add the Activity corresponding to your Tab in the setContent() method using Intent.

Comment: The thing is I have a setup where one activity is running that contains multiple tabs; I think syntactically it's correct, especially since I got it running. I know that passing Intent to setContent() is necessary when each tab is a different activity, but is it also necessary here? The code itself generates no errors.

Comment: Nevermind, finally got it working, not sure how, must have had a typo somewhere along the way that I didn't notice; thanks